# Include a variable in my HTML file from a .js file

Tags: javascript, html, include

EDIT : Thanks everyone for your help.
There is actually a built-in function in p5 that allow to write on
screen and now, it work perfectly.

I have a sketch.js file which contains a `sc` variable.

I want to call the `sc` variable in my index.html file to display it.

I looked at many posts and videos but, it always only shows how to do it if the variable is in the `<script>` header of the same HTML file.

How can I do this if my variable is in an other file?

files : (i'm using p5 )

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  //Square variables
  sQx = 5;
  sQy = 5;
  sQs = 20;
  speed = 5;
  //Rectangle variables
  Rx = 300
  Ry = 300
  Rw = 40
  Rh = 70
  //Points variable
  Px = 300
  Py = 300
  Ps = 10
  //Score variable
  sc = 0
}

function draw() {


  background(100);
  color(255, 204, 0)
  square(sQx, sQy, sQs)
  color(255, 204, 0)

  //Makes the Square move
  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    sQy -= speed
  } else if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    sQy += speed
  } else if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    sQx -= speed;
  } else if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    sQx += speed;
  }
  //rect(Rx, Ry, Rw, Rh)
  //Create the points

  square(Px, Py, 10)
  // Detect if Square is on the points and change the points place
  let d = dist(sQx, sQy, Px, Py)

  if (d <= 30) {
    let RdX = random(0, 400)
    Px = RdX
    let RdY = random(0, 400)
    Py = RdY
    sc = sc + 1
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Sketch</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


  <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <script src="sketch.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="sc"></div>
  <script>
    let value = printSc()
    document.getElementById("sc").innerHTML = "your score is:" + value
  </script>
  <div id="sc"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want display the "sc" value on the screen

sorry if some things could be done differently I'm really new to coding

Comment: HTML can not call anything, it's a markup language. You can use JS to insert sc value into HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But how ?

Comment: you simply need to import `sketch.js` script using a bog standard `<script src` tag. If that doesn't work then you need to provide all code to reproduce the issue, sc could be scoped for all we know

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that

Comment: It already was there and didn't work so I added all my code

Answer (score -1):

You can put this code everywhere in your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.write(sc);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working too. Could i try to send you my full 2 files so you check it out ?

Comment: Please post your code editing your origin post at the top.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this example?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sc"></div>
</body>
<script>
    let value = printSc()
    document.getElementById("sc").innerHTML = value
</script>

</html>
```

script.js

```
function printSc() {
// your logic
    let d = 20
    let sc
    if (d <= 30) {

        sc = d + 1
    }
    return sc
}
```

Comment: d is an other variable I use to measure the distance between two objects

Comment: yes, you can simply return the variable to index.html file. did it work?

Comment: No, sorry would you prefer i send you my full 2 files ?